# php insert mysql cell into div

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table with the values

```
weight_lbs | height_inches|  img_location

150   |   70   |    70_150.jpg

150  |    75  |     75_150.jpg

160   |   70   |    70_160.jpg

160   |   75  |     75_160.jpg
```

PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_GET['gender'])&&isset($_GET['weight'])&&!empty($_GET['gender'])&&!empty($_GET['weight'])) {

$gender = $_GET['gender'];
$height = $_GET['height'];
$weight = $_GET['weight'];

$query = "SELECT `gender`, `height_inches`, `weight_lbs`, `img_location` FROM `tablename` WHERE `gender`='$gender' AND `height_inches`='$height'";

  $query_run = mysql_query($query);

  if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

  $gender = $query_row['gender'];
  $height= $query_row['height_inches']; 
  $img_name = $query_row['img_location']; 

         }
        }
      }
```

I want to run a SQL query using PHP to get the `img_location` cell, based on the `weight_lbs` field.. so selecting `weight_lbs = 150` will return both `70_150.jpg`  and `75_150.jpg`

Then I want to place `70_150.jpg` into a certain DIV (where height is 70) (maybe by using a variable that it gets set to)  and then `75_150.jpg` in another DIV (where height is 75) with a different variable perhaps.

I was thinking of the mysql_results function, doing something like

```
$height70 = mysql_results($query_run, $height=70, img_location)

$height75 = mysql_results($query_run, $height=75, img_location)
```

but that isn't working.

Comment: what 'isn't working' means? error or what? also its better if you provide more code. what is $query_run and img_location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see exactly what you're trying to achieve here but as a stating point, does this help?

```
$query = '
    SELECT height, img_location
    FROM your_table
    WHERE weight = "150"
';

$result = mysql_query($query) 
    or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_query($result)) {

    $weight_150[$row['height']] = $row['img_location'];
}
```

Now based on the values you gave in your example table,

```
// $weight_150['70'] will return 70_150.jpg
// $weight_150['75'] will return 75_150.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysql_results()` parameters are wrong.

From the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

> string mysql_result ( resource $result , int $row [, mixed $field = 0
>   ] )

You need to reference the `row` in the second param, and if you are using the `column` name instead of the offset it needs to be in quotes `""`/`''`

```
$height70 = mysql_results($query_run, 0, "img_location")
$height75 = mysql_results($query_run, 1, "img_location")
```

this assumes that `70` is the first row returned `[0]`, and `75` is the second row returned `[1]`.

---

note: from the top of the manual page-

> **Warning**
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.